# Bootstrap isn't showing on all app pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have created an app and am running it as a test. The app is comprised of using bootstrap to create buttons, fields, headers, and panels. When I run the app, one of the pages is displayed as raw html, displaying the fields as regular html pages.

[image]

The app is written in rails, and the html.erb file is written properly as well:

```
<% header "Edit #{resource_name.to_s.humanize}" %>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

 <div class="form-control">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_confirmation %>
    <span class="label label-info"> Currently waiting confirmation for: <% resource.unconfirmed_email %></span>
  <% end %>
 </div>


<div class="form-group">
 <%= f.label :password %>
 <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
   <span class="help-block">Enter new password</span>
 <% end %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :current_password %>
     <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
       <span class="help-block">Confirm password</span>
     <% end %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 </div>
  <% end %>

  <h3>Cancel my account</h3>

  <p>Delete account <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

  <%= link_to "Back", :back, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
```

I also have the bootstrap-sass gem installed on the system:

```
gem 'devise_zxcvbn'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

The file is also included in the javascript file as well:

```
//= require jquery
//= require global
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require turbolinks
```

How can I get the page to work with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to import the bootstrap styles in your application.scss file.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

and the javascript has to be imported like this:

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Just follow all the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) and you'll be fine.

Comment: I have that line in the scss file as well. I just didn't put it there.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps on the documentation properly and restart your server after installing the gem?

Comment: I have all files in the app working accordingly except for that one.

Comment: I cannot seem to find out how to make that file display itself with a bootstrap ui format